# Is it a breach of policy to select specific PHOTO_REFERENCE and PHOTO_IDs using Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api, photo, google-places

in part, I'm creating a restaurant app. I'm looking to use the PLACE_ID to select the restaurant. If I want to select SPECIFIC photos using a PHOTO_ID or PHOTO_REFERENCE, is that a breach of policy? I'm just looking to use a photo string to pull some specific photos to display on my app, but I'm getting a vibe that google doesn't want you persisting Image/Photo Id's. Is this true? It seems like they want you to select all of the photos associated with the PLACE_ID. I only need specific ones though. Can I do these types of individual callings without violating their policy? Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: I'm not asking for advice, more or less, just asking if the functionality of what google provides has any restrictions or not.

Comment: I think the best approach would be to contact the Google Places API team and ask them about this query.